# How can I fix a faded logo in Outlook email signature

Tags: color, logo, mac, microsoft-office

I created an company-wide email signature template on my MAC starting with an RGB vector logo from Illustrator--converted to a PNG. When some users send an email with the signature template, the logo image looks faded (as if its a watermark) and blurry. This is not consistent with all users, since some signatures appear to be ok. Now, some of the logos placed into a Word document on the PC are faded. When the document is opened on a Mac, the logos usually look fine. --So far the Word documents prints ok, printing isn't an issue with the emails.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Remi, Welcome to GD.SE! If the document and/or email is seen poorly on 1 screen and that same document and/or email is seen on another screen with the correct colors and same files; The issue most likely is the first screen is poorly (color) calibrated/screen settings are different.

Comment: hi! Its definitely not a screen calibration issue. The same screen will see an email the logo and it will be fine. Just some users are sending the logo/signature and its getting faded.

Answer (score 2):

If the email footer is embedded in through individual user Microsoft Outlook preference panel the user has a setting that can render the quality of the image you are placing.
The following link describes the problem and the solution to fix this issue by using an image editor -
[Outlook blurry or fuzzy images](https://emailsignaturerescue.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204154114-Outlook-blurry-or-fuzzy-images) Hope this helps

Another way around is to get your IT department to invest in a bit of software (cant remember what its called) that they can add the footer (across the server end) - our company looked into it but might be a little pricey. It can add user group rules for different departments if you want them to have a footer with targeted messaging.

Answer (score 0):

I also found the same solution to this. The image I was using was a PNG. I changed the image in Preview to JPG. The image was then as the original and no longer looked washed out and faded.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution for this. I think (not able to verify) the image in the signature was a PNG. I saved the image as a JPG and replaced the PNG with the JPG. It was not blurry anymore ;-) !